# Reference or value type?

Tags: c#, arrays, reference, value-type

I started reading more about reference and value types. And I have a problem with this situation:

```
int[] array = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

var result = from element in array
             let v = element * 100
             where v >= 500
             select v;

foreach (var element in result)
    Console.WriteLine(element);
```

How everyone know array is a reference type, but what about my let which is int? When I take apart parts of array which are values type. What are these than?

Comment: The question is a little unclear. `v` is an `int` and of course a value type. What exactly confuses you? Can you give an example of what behaviour you expect or somethng like that? You surely know that your query does not change your array or the elements within.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. The element type is `int`, which is still a value type.

Comment: However the actual *list* is a reference-type whose elements are instances of a value-type.

Comment: *"When I take apart parts of array which are values type. What are these than?"* What are the parts of what I build from parts? Well parts ... or int (value types) in your case.

Comment: In many cases the only way to know this is to know it. In other words, you can't look at the screen and go "oh, yeah, this is a reference type", you have to know that it is. You learn this either by digging, inspecting the types involved, or reading documentation. Next time you remember it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly you are asking what happens when you are manipulating value types, such as `int`.

Technically speaking you can't manipulate value types. Instead what happens is that each time you perform an operation a new value is created.

So in your example `v` is still a value type. However, you can force the compiler to turn a value type into a reference type and vice versa by boxing/unboxing it:

```
Object obj = (object) 10;
int i = (int) obj;
```

Read more about this topic [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `arrays` are always `reference types`. However, an `array` is just a collection of items. The items collected don't change their type just because they are in a collection. An `int` will almost always be an `int` and therefore are `value type`, no matter if it is an `int` in an `array` or not.

If you change your code to

```
Console.WriteLine(element.GetType());
```

you'll see that it will output

```
System.Int32
```

for every element in your result.

Comment: "An `int` will always be an `int`..." You are forgetting about boxing here. Sometimes an int is wrapped in an object.

Comment: @DavidArno true, my answer is very simplyfied, I'll change it to "almost always". ;)

Comment: @DavidArno true, but how is that relevant in this particular case?

Comment: @DavidArno The actual `int`-instance will still stay an int, regardless if it is boxed which itself just creates a *copy* of our `int` on the heap.